# How to get the count of day with most rows with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following rows. `id`, `address`, `timestamp`. Timestamp is a unix timestamp. How can I get the day that has the most rows, and the number of rows in that day using 1 query. I am using MySQL 5.6.34.

Comment: Is this an educational post?

Comment: @WEI_DBA yes it is. Why is this downvoted? I didn't see a duplicate of this and it's a useful question that can be answered clearly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @JackManey This was posted as an education self answer

Comment: @Goose - Generating answers for self-gratification is not the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JackManey When I had this problem I didn't see an existing question for this, so when I found a solution, I posted it Q&A style to help future user having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group the rows by date, use `COUNT(*)` to get the count of rows in each group, and then use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to get the highest count.

```
SELECT DATE(timestampColumn) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This gives error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY date ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1' at line 2`

Comment: Oops, forgot `FROM tablename`

Comment: Yep, that was it. this is even simpler than my answer, thanks!

Comment: @Goose: And it even is correct, whereas yours isn't.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner maybe. I was getting the correct result with my query, but that could be coincidence.

Comment: @Goose: It is. When getting data from a subquery (also called derived table) the data is considered unordered even when it contains an `ORDER BY`. You get the `MAX(total)` correctly, but the `date` is just one of the dates arbitrarily picked. You were lucky to get the correct one.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner because it DESCs by total, the first result will be the row with the highest `COUNT`, no?

Comment: @Goose There's no guarantee that it will select the first row in the subquery when it aggregates.

Comment: @Goose: No, data from a subquery is considered unordered. The DBMS does not have to apply the sort at all and even if it does, `date` in an aggregating query means *any* date, not the *first* date found.